# Проблема вложенных словарей Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

уважаемые питонисты!
Столкнулся с проблемой следующего характера:

Задача: распределить файлы по месяцам и дням, исходя из их названий.
Для распределения файлов сделал такую структуру, постараюсь описать ее так

```
Словарь dict_month с значениями {"месяц": Class Month, ...}
  Класс Month с словарем dict_days = {"день": Class Day, ...}
    Класс Day с списком files = ["название файла", ...]
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в конечном list, вложенный в словарь "дней", который вложен в словарь "месяцев" почему-то записываются названия всех файлов из папки, хотя при выполнении цикла в режиме отладки видно, что запись происходит корректное количество раз (6).

Идентичный подход абсолютно корректно работает на C#.

Для чистоты понимания я прикрепил скриншот сравнения вывода Python, C# и состав папки.
[image: Вывод программ]

К сожалению, я только недавно изучаю Python, но подобное поставило меня в тупик, так как сама программа, исходя из отладки, работает корректна.

Пожалуйста, подскажите - ошибка заключается в способе вывода результата, или сам способ использования словарей таким способом некорректен в Python?

```py
import os

class Month:
    name = ""
    dict_days = {}
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
class Day:
    name = ""
    files = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def get_files_count(self):
        print(len(self.files))
    

    files_list = os.listdir("test") 
    number_files = len(files_list)

    dict_month = {}

    # переменная count создана для проверки количества создания записей
    count = 0

for file in files_list:
    month = file[5] + file[6]
    day = file[8] + file[9]

    # проверяем, существует ли месяц и день в наших словарях
    while True:
        if(month in dict_month):    
            if(day in dict_month[month].dict_days):  
                break
            else: 
                dict_month[month].dict_days[day] = Day(day) 
                break
        else:             
            dict_month[month] = Month(month)
    count += 1
           
        dict_month[month].dict_days[day].files.append(file)
        
    # Вывод результата
    for m in dict_month:
        print(f"Month is: {m}")
        for d in dict_month[m].dict_days:
            print(f"\tDay is: {d}")
            for f in dict_month[m].dict_days[d].files:
                print(f"\t{f}")
```

Ссылки на Pastebin
[Python](https://pastebin.com/Cw5N2Bhf)
[C#](https://pastebin.com/7aiDWu0C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не имеет никакого отношения к работе словарей. Совсем.

У вас для каждого `dict_month[m]` предполагается свой собственный `dict_days`, однако из-за того, что `dict_days` - это переменная класса, то там все свалено в одну кучу.

По семантике это очень похоже, если бы в C# к объявлению добавили `static`. То же самое и про `files`.

Стоит объявить эти переменные через `self` и побольше почитать про то, как работают переменные класса и переменные экземпляра.

```
class Month:
    # в теле класса ничего не объявлять, кроме функций!!!
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.dict_days = {}

class Day:
    # в теле класса ничего не объявлять, кроме функций!!!
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.files = []
```

Полезные ссылки:

- [Understanding Class and Instance Variables in Python 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3)
- [Distinguishing Instance Variables from Class Variables in python](https://dev.to/ogwurujohnson/distinguishing-instance-variables-from-class-variables-in-python-81#:%7E:text=Class%20Variables%20are%20variables%20that,the-same%20for%20each%20instance.)
- [enSO: python class instance variables and class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ёмкий ответ!